# JpaRepository .findAll method returns null values and reapeating list via postman

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

So I am creating a simple stock management project, however, when I query the DB (MySQL) the .findall() method returns the first row multiple times and some column data is null when data is evidently present. Please note, I am using Lombok also.

In addition to the same row being returned, 3 new columns are created every time the query is run.
I feel it could be a mapping issue from entity field to DB column, but everything seems to mathc for me?

Can provide further info if needed.

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Data
//@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long ID;
    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "FirstName", nullable = false)
    private String FirstName;
    @Column(name = "LastName", nullable = false)
    private String LastName;
    @Column(name = "Address", nullable = false)
    private String Address;
    @Column(name = "Mobile", nullable = false)
    private String Mobile;
    @Column(name = "Email", nullable = false)
    private String Email;
    @Column(name = "LastLogin", nullable = false)
    private Date LastLogin;
    @Column(name = "LastUpdated", nullable = false)
    private Date LastUpdated;
}
```

**UserService**

```
@Override
public List<UserModel> getAllUsers() {
    return userRepo.findAll();
}
```

**Controller**

```
 @GetMapping("/getAll")
public ResponseEntity<List<UserModel>> getallUsers(){
    List<UserModel> userModels = (List<UserModel>) userService.getAllUsers();
    return new ResponseEntity<List<UserModel>>(userModels, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: i use Iterable . See here https://github.com/Georges73/springboot-angular-mysql-autocomplete/tree/master/HEROES-BACK-END/heroes-angular-sp-boot-autocomplete

Comment: Don't use `@Data` for entities, that is a bad idea. If anything only use `@Getter` and `@Setter`. Implement a proper `equals` and `hashCode` yourself (see https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Comment: Did you annote with '@autowired' your userRepo in UserService class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, it is appreciated and will give me further angles to keep in mind on future debugging.

The way I solved it in the end was updating the table column names to snake case, i.e. "FirstName" was changed to "first_name". So in hindsight, the mapping was the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If the default implementation of `JpaRepository#findAll` fails (for whatever reason), try your own:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserModelRepository extends JpaRepository<UserModel, Long> {

    @Override
    @Query("SELECT um FROM UserModel um")
    List<UserModel> findAll();

}
```

Note: The query in this example is the same as what JPA generates by default. It should be actually overriden depending on the requirement.

Also, there's no need to cast in your controller. The `getAllUsers()` method already returns a `List<UserModel>`.

Comment: I will try that, thank you.

Regarding the cast, the intellisense is throwing an error and wants a cast. I am unsure why, but if the cast solves it, I don't see an issue in a project this small.

Comment: The query is the same as generated by the default `findAll`.

Comment: It was more about the how than the what, but yes, I should've added that.